# Failure management for a method in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, nestjs

In our nestJS app we are configuring two cron jobs :

```
class SchedularService{
// some private variables here

@Cron("* * * * * *")
async readSomeFiles(){

return await this.fooService.foo();
return await this.fooService.bar();


@Cron("* * * * * *")
async readSomeFiles2(){

return await this.fooService.foo2();
return await this.fooService.bar2();
// 5 more methods



}
```

Now all these methods mentioned parse data from a csv file row by row, push row data into the DB and then upon piushing all rows the csv file is pushed into another folder named `processed_files`.

Incase there are some errors encountered the method has to be called three more times to retry it and if it still fails push the csv file into a folder named `failed_files`.

This how any method of `fooService` looks like and how failure management is being dealt with :

```
async foo(attempt_no: number = 1){
let max_attempts = 3;
let sourcePath = join ('csv_file_store','foo.csv');
let processedPath = 'processed_files'
let failedDirPath = 'failed_files'

try
{
// read contents of file and parse data line by line
// push row by row to DB
}

catch(error)
{
      console.log("Error processing file: ", error);
      
      if (attempt_no < maxAttempts) {
        return await this.foo(attempt_no + 1);
      } else {
        console.log("Error processing file after  attempts.");
  
        // Moving file to failed_files directory
        const targetFilePath = join(failedDirPath, 'foo.csv');
        renameSync(sourceFilePath, targetFilePath);
        console.log("File has been moved to the 'failed_files' directory.");
  
        return {
          status: {
            statusCode: 500,
            statusMessage: `File processing failed with error: ${error.message}`
          }
        };
      }
    }
 }
```

Now incase there is some error in the service layer the task we need to work on is to ensure that call the same method three times and if it still does not work it will be pushed into `failed_files` folder.

The code is to be re-factored to not pass `attempt_no` at the service layer and instead maintain a state outside of the service layer. Need help on how the state can be configured outside of the service.

Comment: Is `readSecondAllocationData` the same as `foo`? Otherwise this doesn't really make sense

Comment: Yeah `readSecondAllocationData`  is `foo` , Cannot expose the business logic because of data privacy.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to fix it, please choose either name

Comment: What do you mean by "*maintain a state outside of the service layer.*"? That you want to put the retry logic in the `readSomeFiles` method of the scheduler service instead of the foo service? Or just that you don't want an `attempt_no` parameter in the public `foo` method?

Comment: I do not want `attempt_no` parameter in the public `foo` method.

Comment: Then simply put the code in a private method that has the parameter and still is recursive, and from your public `foo` method (without a parameter) call the private method with the initial value for the parameter.